# Anything like SciPy in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, math, scipy

Looking further into the differences between Python and Ruby, is there a Ruby equivalent to SciPy, or what other scientific math gems are available for Ruby?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's nothing quite as mature or well done as SciPy, but check out [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com/) and [Numerical Ruby](http://narray.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: SciRuby has actually been restarted: sciruby.com. There's also a matrix library (NMatrix) which handles sparse as well as dense. It's not finished yet. `gem install nmatrix`

Answer (score 2):

rnum

> Ruby Numerical Library is a linear
>   algebra package using Blas and Lapack.

http://rnum.rubyforge.org/

Site has some speed comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Someone else mentioned NArray and Ara T. Howard's / @drawohara's SciRuby.

But there's also a new [SciRuby project](http://sciruby.com) (proceeding with Ara's and Masahiro Tanaka's blessings) which includes a dense and sparse matrix gem, [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix). It's not finished yet, but it does basic stuff.

The [SciRuby github account](http://github.com/SciRuby) also has a bunch of other useful gems, including statsample (for statistics) and rubyvis (for visualization).

Answer (score 0):

linalg https://github.com/wedesoft, installation instructions: http://www.quora.com/Installation-Instructions/How-do-I-install-Ruby-linalg-library-on-Mac