# Ruby equivalent of NumPy

Tags: ruby, numpy

I'd like to be able to get averages, medians, percentiles, etc. I've been looking all over and can't find anything like it. I realize that Ruby isn't used very much in the scientific world, but there has to exist at least a very basic library in Ruby that does math, right?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775013/scientific-programming-with-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703717/anything-like-scipy-in-ruby

Comment: Not used much in the scientific world? We better tell the DNA sequencing people.

Comment: @Tin Man: can you give some pointers to large scale ruby projects for DNA sequencing?

Answer (score 11):

How about ruby narray?

http://narray.rubyforge.org/

If you look at the methods, there is a section on statistics that covers your use cases:

http://narray.rubyforge.org/SPEC.en

You might also want to look at the ruby bindings to the GSL:

http://ruby-gsl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: A new version of NArray has been released. The link is old.

Answer (score 9):

[SciRuby](http://sciruby.com) is working on this. We're actually working on [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) as a replacement for [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/). The most relevant library for you, however, would likely be [Statsample](http://github.com/SciRuby/statsample).

And, as mentioned by JoshAdel, [Ruby/GSL](http://ruby-gsl.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty useful gem. We have a fork of it in [SciRuby's github account](http://github.com/SciRuby) which supports NMatrix instead of NArray.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the development of NMatrix is not active in 2019. On the other hand, NArray has improved performance and continues to release new versions.

On benchmarking, NArray is much faster than NMatrix.

I strongly recommend NArray.

https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray