# How to take an array and operate each element against each other element

Tags: ruby, arrays

Here is what I'm doing:

```
(1..999).each do |a|
    (1..999).each do |b|
      if Math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2) % 1 == 0 && a + b + Math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2) == 1000 && a >= b
            puts a * b * Math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2) 
        end     
    end
end
```

What is happening is that `a` and `b` are interchangeable in the formulas so there are two matches and thus `puts` gets outputted twice. To fix this, I added `a >= b` and now it only gets outputted once. But, if `a == b`it outputs it twice. I know that a and b will always be different in the example I'm using, but this seems like bad design to me.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better pattern in Ruby for taking an array and comparing it to it self?
2. How can I avoid it outputting twice *always*. I could set a variable that if changed before the start of the next loop would break out. Is that the proper way to do this?

Comment: I think the only reason you are having an issue is that you are using a pre-defined range of numbers. Will you always have that? If the array contents are not predictable and you want the euclidean distance between every combination (seems that's what you are looking for), then you will have to do that calculation. Perhaps you could use [narray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653994/ruby-equivalent-of-numpy) to abstract your matrix multiplication?

Comment: @kobejohn this is a part of project Euler (problem 9 to be exact). But I thought the code wasn't as clean as it could be. Wanted to see if I could improve it a bit. So, yes I do know it will always be between 1..999, but this isn't designed to be industrial strength.

Comment: I see. My bad that I missed point 1.: it's actually the same array. The solution by austinbv is a nice demonstration of ruby's flexibility and readability when done right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#using combination
(1..999).to_a.combination(2).each do |low, high|
  if Math.sqrt(low**2 + high**2) % 1 == 0 && low + hight + Math.sqrt(low**2 + high**2) == 1000
    puts low * high * Math.sqrt(low**2 + high**2)
  end
end
```

Edited to use a little better practice (each block with first and second for arrays of arrays)