# Scientific modules for Ruby

Tags: ruby, numpy, mod-wsgi

I've been using quite a number of Python modules such as Numpy in large machine learning projects. Previously, I used Django for the web application and mod_wsgi as a front end to these. Now, someone is making the case to transfer to Ruby on Rails. Are similar libraries available for Ruby?

Comment: That's a tough case to make because from what I understand there's nothing in ruby that even comes close.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653994/ruby-equivalent-of-numpy , and the questions I linked to in the comments section of that question.

Answer (score 2):

As Benjamin Tan pointed out, [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com) is working on this. Commenters rightly noted that not much work has been done on the [sciruby gem](http://github.com/SciRuby/sciruby), but [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) is under extremely active development. The goal is to replace [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/).

There are also quite a few stable gems associated with SciRuby: [Statsample](http://github.com/SciRuby/statsample), [distribution](http://github.com/SciRuby/distribution), [minimization](http://github.com/SciRuby/minimization), [integration](http://github.com/SciRuby/integration), [Rubyvis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/) (a Ruby port of Protovis), and so on.

SciRuby actually just got Google Summer of Code support, too, and a grant from the Ruby Association a few months ago, so we're hopeful that it will go places.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the lead developers for NMatrix and a co-founder of the SciRuby project.

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com/).

Comment: Is the project dead/not doing well? The last contribution to the SciRuby repos was 2 months ago and it looks like it was/is still in very early stages.

Comment: Well you're right. As pguardiario mentioned, Ruby is to lagging far far behind compared to Python. Although, if you know exactly that you're looking for, you might have better luck.

Comment: @JeffTratner, it's still active. Most development is happening in the NMatrix repo, not the SciRuby repo. http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix